# PHPMailer issue with recipient

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I use PHPMailer to send some email to one ore more detinations.
However I encountered a problem. Here comes:
This is my code:

```
      $mail2->AddAddress($cliemail);
      $mail2->AddCC('important@destination.com');
      $mail2->SetFrom('important@destination.com', "...");
      $mail2->AddReplyTo('important@destination.com', "...");
      $mail2->Subject = 'Email subject... '.$wnume;
      $mail2->AltBody = 'To be able to see this email please...'; 
      $mail2->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
      $mail2->AddAttachment('teste/quiz.pdf'); // attachment
      $mail2->Send();
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    }
```

So, my email must be sent from **important@destination.com** (it is another email of course)
And it gets sent to $cliemail, but it does not arrive to the CC (*important@destination.com*)
So apparently I cannot send an email to myself... Is this normal?

What could be the cause?

I tried to remove the AddCC and try to simply send the email directly to *important@destination.com* but it still does not arrive.

Is this some setting in my email account that I must do in order to be able to receive an email from myself?

So:

1. When I send the email to a third party email address using the above
   code, it works
2. When I send the email to myself (the sender) (the same address that is the "SetFrom") it does not arrive
3. Even if I set the CC with my address, it still does not arrive, while it arrives at the main destination address ($cliemail)

Please help

Comment: This sounds like it's not a problem with PHPMailer, but with the relay of messages to your inbox. Are you using SMTP, or submitting to a local mail server with mail or sendmail options? If you can see them, check your mail server logs, and don't forget to look in your spam folder.

Comment: I am not using SMTP, and I do not have access to the mail server logs.

Comment: You either need to get access to the logs, or switch to SMTP. If you can't use SMTP directly, you need to find a better ISP.